# Combining pictures with timestamp

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have multiple pictures defined with timestamp, for instance:

```
face-01.jpg
face-02.jpg
...
screen-01.jpg
screen-02.jpg
...
```

I need to merge the "face" pics with the "screen" ones using "montage" command of imagemagik. Any suggestion?

```
montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x face-01.jpg screen-01.jpg
```

Comment: You forgot to name a third image file, the output image. -- So if you add that: what does not work with this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following loop to create montages of corresponding face/screen images.

```
for face in face*
do
   montage "$face" "screen-${face//[^0-9]/}.jpg" -mode Concatenate -tile x1 "montage_${face}"
done
```

Comment: @silviolor: you've *'accepted'* dogbane's answer. I think you should additionally also *'upvote'* it...